# Unable to activate environments

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have been trying to activate environments using anaconda prompt but keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lihi\anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 105, in main
    return activator_main()
  File "C:\Users\lihi\anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\activate.py", line 838, in main
    print(activator.execute(), end='')
  File "C:\Users\lihi\anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\activate.py", line 110, in execute
    return getattr(self, self.command)()
  File "C:\Users\lihi\anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\activate.py", line 88, in activate
    return self._finalize(self._yield_commands(builder_result), self.tempfile_extension)
  File "C:\Users\lihi\anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\activate.py", line 78, in _finalize
    tf.write(ensure_binary(self.command_join.join(commands)))
  File "C:\Users\lihi\anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\activate.py", line 536, in ensure_binary
    return value.encode(encoding)
  File "C:\Users\lihi\anaconda\lib\encodings\cp1255.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 859-862: character maps to <undefined>
```

I understand that there is a problematic character somewhere but do not know where to look for it or how to fix this.

Comment: Can you run any conda commands? What is the output of `conda info --envs`

Comment: Yes, everything else seems to be working fine, and the command you mentioned gives me a list of the existing environments.

Comment: Can you [edit] the output of that into the post? There seems to be something wrong with one of the names of your environments.

Comment: (base) C:\>conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  C:\Users\lihi\anaconda
hw1_env                  C:\Users\lihi\anaconda\envs\hw1_env
myArabycia               C:\Users\lihi\anaconda\envs\myArabycia